# Publish c# Project with Custom App Root folder in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish

I kindly need some assistance. I have finalized coding my application which works fine but i'm getting a bit of challenge publishing the app. I have managed to copy the database to the output directory however, adding the images directory to the output directory has become very big issue to me. The image directory contains custom images uploadable via the app. I did some changes to the .csproj but in vain.

**.csproj**

```
<Target Name="ContentsBeforeBuild" AfterTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="images\*.*">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

and also used

```
<Target Name="ContentsBeforeBuild" AfterTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="images\**">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

And this is the code for retrieving and displaying the images onto my app. It works fine before publishing the app but after publishing, it returns directory notfound exception.

```
 String paths = Application.StartupPath.Substring(0, (Application.StartupPath.Length - 10));

                    String imagePath = paths+"\\images\\"+col["itemPhoto"].ToString();
```

The error. Unable to access the image directory after publishing

[image: The image not found directory error]

Is their any other way i can write the code so that it gets the images from the app?
Kindy i need some assistance.

Over a week trying to publish my app .. Please please help

**.csproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{5765EB29-19B9-4FC8-8414-B033C956AE48}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Shop_POS</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Shop POS</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <PublishUrl>C:\Users\dansyo\Desktop\pos\spos\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>2</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>logo1_15W_icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>986913D78C02BC6448BB7EBB687285F9D3AB2FD4</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestKeyFile>Shop POS_TemporaryKey.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.DirectoryServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AddEmployeeDialog.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="AddEmployeeDialog.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AddEmployeeDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="AddItemDialog.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="AddItemDialog.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AddItemDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ComboboxItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessProfile.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="BusinessProfile.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>BusinessProfile.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="DatabaseHandler.cs" />
    <Compile Include="DeleteAlldata.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="DeleteAlldata.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DeleteAlldata.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ForgottenPassword.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ForgottenPassword.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ForgottenPassword.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="GenerateBarCode.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="GenerateBarCode.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>GenerateBarCode.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="GenerateBarCodeDialog.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="GenerateBarCodeDialog.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>GenerateBarCodeDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="OutOfStock.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="OutOfStock.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>OutOfStock.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="PremiumActivation.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="PremiumActivation.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>PremiumActivation.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="RecoverAccount.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="RecoverAccount.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>RecoverAccount.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Getter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainActivity.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainActivity.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainActivity.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Login.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Login.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Login.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Methods.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PrintMyCart.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="PrintMyCart.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>PrintMyCart.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Register.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Register.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Register.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ResetPassword.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ResetPassword.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ResetPassword.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="RestoreDefault.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="RestoreDefault.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>RestoreDefault.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SellerActivity.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SellerActivity.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>SellerActivity.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="EmpMethod.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SellerActivitySearchInventory.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SellerActivitySearchInventory.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>SellerActivitySearchInventory.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Splash.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Splash.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Splash.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="TaxDialog.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="TaxDialog.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>TaxDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="TblCompanyProfile.cs" />
    <Compile Include="TblInventory.cs" />
    <Compile Include="TblRegister.cs" />
    <Compile Include="TblSales.cs" />
    <Compile Include="TblSellers.cs" />
    <Compile Include="TblSettings.cs" />
    <Compile Include="UpdateDelEmpDialog.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UpdateDelEmpDialog.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UpdateDelEmpDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UpdateDelInventoryDialog.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UpdateDelInventoryDialog.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UpdateDelInventoryDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="AddEmployeeDialog.resx">
      <DependentUpon>AddEmployeeDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="AddItemDialog.resx">
      <DependentUpon>AddItemDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="BusinessProfile.resx">
      <DependentUpon>BusinessProfile.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="DeleteAlldata.resx">
      <DependentUpon>DeleteAlldata.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="ForgottenPassword.resx">
      <DependentUpon>ForgottenPassword.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="GenerateBarCode.resx">
      <DependentUpon>GenerateBarCode.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="GenerateBarCodeDialog.resx">
      <DependentUpon>GenerateBarCodeDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="OutOfStock.resx">
      <DependentUpon>OutOfStock.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="PremiumActivation.resx">
      <DependentUpon>PremiumActivation.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="RecoverAccount.resx">
      <DependentUpon>RecoverAccount.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="MainActivity.resx">
      <DependentUpon>MainActivity.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Login.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Login.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="PrintMyCart.resx">
      <DependentUpon>PrintMyCart.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Register.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Register.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="ResetPassword.resx">
      <DependentUpon>ResetPassword.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="RestoreDefault.resx">
      <DependentUpon>RestoreDefault.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="SellerActivity.resx">
      <DependentUpon>SellerActivity.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="SellerActivitySearchInventory.resx">
      <DependentUpon>SellerActivitySearchInventory.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Splash.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Splash.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="TaxDialog.resx">
      <DependentUpon>TaxDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="UpdateDelEmpDialog.resx">
      <DependentUpon>UpdateDelEmpDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="UpdateDelInventoryDialog.resx">
      <DependentUpon>UpdateDelInventoryDialog.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="Shop POS_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="images\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="logo\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="favicon.ico" />
    <Content Include="images\alfa_romeo.jpg" />
    <Content Include="logo1_15W_icon.ico" />
    <Content Include="logo\DAEWOO.jpg" />
    <Content Include="Properties\add.png" />
    <None Include="Resources\za.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup />

<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Try putting some sample file in the images folder while publishing, as empty folders may not get published.

Comment: Thanks Srikanth, i have do so, i have added two images but still the error is still their. The image path is not recognisable. Executes directory exception error

Comment: Is the folder copied to output directory? If yes, I would compare the folder structure - often times relative path of Custom Folder differs from local dev box to contents after publishing. If logging is enabled, I would add a log statement which logs imagePath (or paths).

Comment: Yeah it is copied. also, after publishing the application, i can see the folder inside the application files with the files inside. Big issue is the code to retrieve image after app is published.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is the way how you are trying to access images folder. Like I said in my comment, the path won't match after you deploy the application (as you are doing substring).

Since you are copying images folder, you don't need to do substring.

Just try this:

```
String imagePath = Application.StartupPath+"\\images\\"+col["itemPhoto"].ToString();
```

Could you modify your csproj file,

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="images\alfa_romeo.jpg">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>    
</ItemGroup>
```

and remove your existing

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="images\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

and this line:

[image]

Comment: Thanks sam for your reply. It is still returning the same type of error.

Comment: did you get a chance to log imagePath? and does it exist in the expected location (imagePath)?

Comment: Hae Sam , you answer is correct but the image directory is not found. I'm uploading images to the image directory residing at the root of the application an works before publishing but after publishing , i don't know what is not happening and i modified the .csproj to copy the image directory to the outputdirectory. Kindly help i know you can help me because i can feel you have the experience

Comment: sorry that I could not respond to your message but noticed that you solved the issue by yourself.

Comment: I appreciated so much for the tip... But i just wonder why i can't do it using .csproj like the others because even the database has an issue if i publish the app in different computer. Could you kindly give me a tip off because is my first app in c# to publish and over two weeks now struggling to publish it

Comment: I updated the answer. I see some issue with your csproj file. Please post your observations

Comment: Hi sam, not working...kindly show me the changes that you have made

Comment: Can you try selecting "Copy Always" content setting, instead of "Copy if Newer". Also I have attached the screenshot of working sample project.

Comment: @DanielNyamasyo Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: I have switched to SQLite database from SSMS database because i wanted a portable database. Currently have not tried publishing.  Once i will be publishing the app, i will let you know. Thanks for your ultimate concern

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Guy. Finally i had to do it programmatically and it worked. I added the images directory programmatically on my app launch and worked amazing.

```
 bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists("images");

            if (!exists)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("images");
```